# Auth using external Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth

I have a website that all I really want to have is the UI (html, css, client-side js,..etc).

I want to set up an API that provides all the business login and Auth.

Is this possible and does anyone have any resources that they can point me to, to get up and running?

I have two node apps, one for the UI side and the other for the API.

I want to protect pages on the UI side with the API side. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also both the node instances reside on the same server just on different ports.

Comment: did you try to use `express-jwt`? for `oauth`?

Comment: No I was looking at passport, but I don't know if it's possible. I'm just wondering if it's possible and if it is do you or anyone have any links to point me in the right direction. I'm assuming from you statement that it is possible and those would be the libraries I should look at. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWT looks like it might be worth considering.

Here's an interesting presentation (this is from a Vue.js conference):

["A Token Walks Into a SPA"](https://www.vuemastery.com/conferences/vueconf-toronto-2018/a-token-walks-into-a-spa/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=7_top_talks_from_vueconf_toronto_now_live&utm_term=2018-12-06)